# mongo update query given error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-scala

```
Coll.update(condition, new BasicDBObject("$set", data), true, true))
```

This is my update query in mongodb for some records it gives result as

```
{ "err" :  null  , "updatedExisting" : true , "n" : 1 , "ok" : 1.0}
```

and at that time stored update query execute properly.

but for some records it give result as

```
{ "err" : "not okForStorage" , "code" : 12527 , "n" : 0 , "ok" : 1.0}
```

records neither update nor stoare in db

in data there are multiple `BasicDBList` (list) used.

if some one knows plz reply

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

More than likely there are invalid characters in your document fields/keys.

For example, you can't have a period `.` or a dollar sign `$` in your field names.

If you send the output from the following, I can help more.

```
System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . Yes there was "." in my fields name so update query is not working ones again thanks for replying.