# MongoDB not okForStorage error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've looked around quite a bit concerning this error, it seems that Mongo won't accept a `.` or a `$` in an update, yet I still get this error

```
{ [MongoError: not okForStorage]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'not okForStorage',
  code: 12527,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 18,
  ok: 1 }
```

This is the object I'm updating:

```
{
status: "open",
type: "item",
parentId: "4fa13ba2d327ca052d000003",
_id: "4fa13bd6d327ca052d000012",
properties: {
  titleInfo: [
   { title: "some item" }
  ]
  }
}
```

And I'm updating it to:

```
{
fedoraId: 'aFedoraLib:438',
status: "closed",
type: "item",
parentId: "4fa13ba2d327ca052d000003",
_id: "4fa13bd6d327ca052d000012",
properties: {
  titleInfo: [
   { title: "some item" }
  ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post a code example reproducing the issue as a github issue please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So for people getting the same error:
It's due to the fact that I was including the _id, which Mongo doesn't like apparently

Comment: Note: Embedded objects can have `_id` field. Looks like this error could appear for several reasons. here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041109/mongo-update-query-given-error

Answer (score 12):

Another possible cause I just ran into: storing an object which has periods in the string keys.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem for a key with period. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: MongoDB does not allow `.` or `$` in field names - they have special semantic meaning. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions

Comment: I ran into the same problem with EJSON `$date` keys that I didn't convert back to normal JSON.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this error when trying to save a JSON structure with this key-value pair (coming straight out of an AngularJS app):

```
 "$$hashKey":"021"
```

Removing just that key fixed the problem. For others using Angular, it looks like calling Angular's built-in `angular.toJson` client-side eliminates the $$hashkey keys. From their forums:

```
$scope.ngObjFixHack = function(ngObj) {
    var output;

    output = angular.toJson(ngObj);
    output = angular.fromJson(output);

    return output;
}
```