# Not Ok for storage on subfield update

Tags: mongodb

I want to run this command

```
db.hospitals.update( { "coordinates.lng": { $lt: -9.034882 } , display:1 },
                    { $set: {"coordinates.lng":{$inc : 0.75}}},
                    { multi: true }
                  )
```

All I get is  : not okForStorage
coordinates is an embedded document and this is its structure :

```
coordinates{
  lat:
  lg:
}
```

As requested

```
db.hospitals.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52ae09f8211b6f57548b4568"),
        "active" : 0,
        "author" : "52cb29b0211b6fd9248b456b",
        "coordinates" : {
                "lat" : 35.691048,
                "lng" : 139.701065
        },
        "date" : ISODate("2013-10-24T18:41:42Z"),
       "display" : 0

}
```

Help please !

Comment: This could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041109/mongo-update-query-given-error

Comment: The answer says that there shouldn't be a . in my fieldname, then how can I update subfields ?

Comment: can you send me the output of db.hospitals.findOne()

Comment: I added it to the question ! :)

Comment: I think this is a MongoDB shell Bug

Comment: which version of mongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{ $set: {"coordinates.lng": {$inc: 0.75}}}
```

This is not how you `$inc` a field. ^ Do this instead:

```
{ $inc: {"coordinates.lng": 0.75}}
```

Comment: You are not 72K reputation for nothing! 
Thanks a lot